# System.loadLibrary in react-native android project causes SIGSEGV segfault

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, react-native, java-native-interface

I'm currently very new to both Android and React Native development.

I'm trying out a third party library, and I wish to use in a react-native app. The library is written in C++ and provided by the vendor in form of a .so file that they say should go in,

```
\android\app\src\jniLibs\armeabi\libTestThing.so
```

and a Java wrapper that goes in

```
\android\app\libs\TestThing.jar
```

Now, if I create a blank new project with Android Studio and call `System.loadLibrary("TestThing")` in the onCreate of the main application, it all works fine.

If I, however, generate a blank project with "react-native init", then use the same folder structure and do the same call, I get a SIGSEGV as soon as the loadLibrary statement is executed even though the files are there and have been added as dependency in the build.gradle file as in the first project.

How could I make this work, what could I try or check ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I faced similar case. Did you find any solutions ?